# Basic Javascript: Cannot output result on html

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to learn Javascript by making a simple calculator, but somehow the result of the calculation doesn't show up. I'm wondering what's wrong with my code. I've tried many ways to understand the error, but I still don't know why. The calculation works just fine in the console, it's just the output that seems to have the problem.

Can somebody help me?

```js
function calc(){


  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var calculate;

if (op == "add") {
  calculate = a + b;
} else if (op == "min"){
  calculate = a - b;
}else if (op == "div"){
  calculate = a / b;
}else if (op == "mul"){
  calculate = a * b;
}

console.log(calculate);
document.querySelector("#result").innerHtml = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/main.js">
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Value 1: <input type="text" name="" value="" id="value1">
      Value 2: <input id="value2" type="text" name="" value="">
      Operator:
      <select id="operator" class="" name="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="min">Min</option>
        <option value="div">Div</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" onclick="calc()" name="button">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <div id="result">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**innerHtml** is invalid attribute, you need to use **innerHTML** instead like:

```
document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = calculate;
```

Comment: though they should probably want to use `textContext` instead of `innerHTML`

Comment: Or `innerText`.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I'll note that :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `textContent` instead of `innerHtml`

```js
function calc(){


  var a = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value1").value);
  var b = parseInt(document.querySelector("#value2").value);
  var op = document.querySelector("#operator").value;
  var calculate;

if (op == "add") {
  calculate = a + b;
} else if (op == "min"){
  calculate = a - b;
}else if (op == "div"){
  calculate = a / b;
}else if (op == "mul"){
  calculate = a * b;
}

console.log(calculate);
document.querySelector("#result").textContent = calculate;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <script src="js/main.js">
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      Value 1: <input type="text" name="" value="" id="value1">
      Value 2: <input id="value2" type="text" name="" value="">
      Operator:
      <select id="operator" class="" name="">
        <option value="add">Add</option>
        <option value="min">Min</option>
        <option value="div">Div</option>
        <option value="mul">Multiply</option>
      </select>
      <button type="button" onclick="calc()" name="button">Calculate</button>
    </form>

    <div id="result">
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
An "id" should be unique within a page and should not 
be used more than once value1 and value2 in doesn't 
recognise by documents.querySelector() so instead of 
this use
Var a = 
parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").value);
var b = 
parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").value);
```